# Populate a list of ngResource from a local variable?

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

I have a basic ngResource defined per:

```
  angular.module('factories', []).factory('SeedSource', [
    '$resource', function($resource) {
      return $resource('/seed-sources/:id/', {
        id: '@id'
      }, {
        update: {
          method: 'PUT'
        }
      });
    }
  ]);
```

And in my Controller I would like to be able to populate a list of this resource from a local variable instead of the traditional `.query()` method, for instance:

```
 $scope.seed_sources = json_array_of_seed_sources;
```

This works up until the point I need to call an ngResource method such as:

```
 seed_source.$save()
```

I know I can go the long way and just add each item to `$scope.seed_sources` individually each as a `new Seeder(...)` but I was hoping there might be a cleaner way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save an array of resources, use the class method:

```
for (let i=0; i<seed_sources.length; i++) {
    SeedSource.save(seed_sources[i], function(source) {
        angular.copy(source, seed_sources[i]);
    });
};
```